# how to set date-picker based on another picking using jquery?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

how to set date-picker based on another picking using jquery ?
for example; my start date can be" 01.01.2010 "date before this date should be pasive and should not be selected.

```js
$('#kid').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(value, ui) {
        var today = new Date().getTime(), 
            dob = new Date(value).getTime();
            age = today - dob;
            yoa = Math.floor(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25); // age / ms / sec / min / hour / days in a year
        if(yoa < 5){
            under5();
        }else{
            overOrEqual10();
        }
$
    },
    maxDate: '-0yr',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: '-0yr',
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="kid" />
<div class="checked" id="age"></div>
```

Comment: Please define `based on another picking`?

Comment: i want to Select a date range after

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. You said `after`, after what? Is there already a predefined daterangepicker in the page somewhere? More information would be helpful.